# An error occured when i try to build an android project that i generated with capacitor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I developped an an application with IONIC, I wanted to run it on an andoid device but when i generated the the android project with Capacitor and I ran it in Android Studio I had this error when I tried to build it :

AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-24:58: AAPT: error: resource string/activity_name (aka io.ionic.starter:string/activity_name) not found.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOQ95.png)

Comment: Please add the commands that you have used to build the project.
Usually, you should use `ionic build && npx cap sync android` and then your project should build successfully in android studio.

Comment: To build the project, I run this commands : ionic build and npx cap add android

Comment: no, this won't work, it's not enough.. check my answer below

Comment: I tried your command, but I still have the error

Comment: two things, delete your android folder and add it again.. also post a screenshot of your dependencies list from package.json here.

Comment: I finally use cordova, it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`ionic build` is required every time you make changes and want them to be updated on the native side.

`ionic capacitor add android` only once while adding a new platform

After this, use these for future changes

`ionic build && ionic capacitor sync android` (if you have added any new package/plugin)

`ionic build && ionic capacitor copy android` (if only code has been changed)

Note: `ionic capacitor` and `npx cap` both can be used..
[Reference Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/build) [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins)